# Intercepting JPA query to calculate the key fields

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I am quite new to JPA. I have a particular repository that uses the keys that have parts that are set by the caller and some values that are automatically calculated using these values. There is a need for this :)

Since the keys and entities are simple Java classes it appears to me that I need to put my code that modifies the key (or substitutes it with an internal one with additional values) is the repository implementation. However I do not think that copying the code from SimpleJpaRepository to my custom repositories is a good idea...I think that something should be possible with the entity manager. Basically what I need is  proxy that gets called every time something like find() or delete() is called, takes the entity, updates its key, passes the call over to the real repository implementation.

Could someone point me to the right direction or an example that does something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In JPA, you have a bunch of events for this, just chose the one that suits you best. It looks like you are looking for `@PrePersist`.

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/annotations/callback

That said, if the data of these fields is calculated based only in the data of the other fields, it goes against database normalization. A more sensate approach would be make the calculated field `@Transient` and provide only the getters, that will calculate the values based in the persistent fields.

Comment: Well, we do not care about the normalization because we are dealing with the database that favors DEnormalization ;) - Cassandra.

Comment: No, that does not work because the is no call back like "PreLoad". And also it does not seem that I am expected to modify the entities (or their keys) in these callbacks.

Comment: `PreLoad` is meaningless because before loading it, the object just does not exist in memory. `PostLoad` would be useful for setting the **calculated** attributes, but I agree it is not the place if you want to persist these attributes (in that case, use `PrePersist` or `PreUpdate`)

Comment: To be very specific: I have a primary key (a string) that I use to generate two more components of my primary key. These components are used along with the original string to create a composite primary key for Cassandra where some values are used for row key and the rest for the clustering key. Basically, I have a real primary key (from the high-level data model perspective) and the storage-specific keys for optimization. I need to calculate these. But the algorithms for them are different and I cannot link them to the key POJO.